# Insert list elements with jquery after img

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html structure:

```
<ul id="comments_notifications_list" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><img src="loader.png" class="noty" style="display: none;"><li>
</ul>
```

---

Now i am trying to add add some content after the loader. The code should be always updated, so after() will not work because the `<li>` will be incremented.

```
$('.noty').after('<li> Name: ' + jd.name + '</li>');
```

---

How can i do that? basically the `<li>` elements should be dynamic inserted and the img always preserved.

Comment: I don't get it, incremented how? If you're trying to append, use `append` ?

Comment: Your code works fine. But you will create more invalid HTML (your current HTML is already invalid).

Comment: use this 

$("comments_notifications_list").append("<li class = \"your_class_name\">li Content</li>"

Comment: @adeneo append() or after() will not refresh the dom.  html() will do that.

Comment: huh, refresh the DOM ?

Comment: @ِAllloush i am using this with ajax requests.

Comment: Oh, you mean remove all other LI's ***but*** the first one, before you insert new ones

Comment: `$('#comments_notifications_list li:not(:first)').remove()`

Comment: @user2990084 yes is understand what you mean, i will place you simple code for mine used to retrieve notifications from ajax call and place them in ul tage

Comment: @adeneo yes will solve the issue, but did not seem very clean. This could not be done in one line of code?

Comment: That is one line of code ?

Comment: Well, that's how it works, if you want to keep the first LI, you have to call remove on the other LI's, and then start adding the new LI's.

Comment: @adeneo please add as answer to accept it.

Comment: @user2990084 it would be a lot easier to put the image outside of the list and just replace the content of the list, styling could be done to look the same with css

Answer (score 1):

I was confused reading your post originally...

```js
// Create a new <li /> after the <li> containing .noty
$('.noty').parent().after("<li>blah</li>");

// Insert new content after .noty
$('.noty').after("<li>blah</li>");

// Insert new content after the UL containing .noty
$('.noty').closest("ul").after("<p>Foo</p>");
```